# golang threading model comparison

Tags: multithreading, go, thread-safety

I have a piece of data

```
type data struct {
    // all good data here
    ...
}
```

This data is owned by a manager and used by other threads for reading only. The manager needs to periodically update the data. How do I design the threading model for this? I can think of two options:

1.

```
type manager struct {
    // acquire read lock when other threads read the data.
    // acquire write lock when manager wants to update.
    lock sync.RWMutex
    // a pointer holding a pointer to the data
    p *data
}
```

2.

```
type manager struct {
    // copy the pointer when other threads want to use the data.
    // When manager updates, just change p to point to the new data.
    p *data
}
```

Does the second approach work? It seems I don't need any lock. If other threads get a pointer pointing to the old data, it would be fine if manager updates the original pointer. As GoLang will do GC, after all other threads read the old data it will be auto released. Am I correct?

Comment: As long as your logic is OK with the potential for a worker to get stale data... That said, you may be dooming yourself and any future maintainers to some severe headaches if you don't fully lock it as the read behavior could be undefined. These issues are very difficult to debug once they start causing problems. It's better to just nip it in the bud and lock it.

Comment: The second approach does not work because it has a data race on the field `p`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón why? The reader will get either old p (which is fine) or new p

Comment: When writing good solid code, there isn't really such a thing as an OK race condition. They are pretty much always bad and should be avoided despite the costs. I would suggest a slightly different approach though because many readers could starve the write lock. Only lock when writing, and disallow reading when the write lock is locked. This works with your data because you aren't concerned if a reader is already working on old data while the writer updates it.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld There's no guarantee that the program will read either the old value or the new value.  See https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option is fine and perhaps simplest to do. However, it could lead to poor performance with many readers as it could struggle to obtain a write lock.

As the comments on your question have stated, your second option (as-is) can cause a race condition and lead to unpredictable behaviour.

You could implement your second option by using [atomic.Value](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value). This would allow you to store the pointer to some data struct and atomically update this for the next readers to use. For example:

```
// Data shared with readers
type data struct {
   // all the fields
}

// Manager
type manager struct {
    v atomic.Value
}

// Method used by readers to obtain a fresh copy of data to 
// work with, e.g. inside loop
func (m *manager) Data() *data {
    return m.v.Load().(*data)
}

// Internal method called to set new data for readers
func (m *manager) update() {
    d:=&data{
        // ... set values here
    }
    m.v.Store(d)
}
```